# Evitar que openssl pida contraseña

Tags: openssl

¿Que tal? tengo el siguiente comando de openssl

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificado_destino.pfx -inkey clave -in Certificado_original.crt
```

¿Como puedo lograr que este comando no me pida clave?, pues me dice "Enter password" y luego que repita, alguien sabe? espero que alguien me ayude gracias

Necesito que valla con pkcs12, para cifrar un certificado, y este cifrado es requerido por el sistema que se maneja en mi pais, no puedo quitarle el comando "pkcs12"

Al utilizar el comando passout:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey privada -in certificado.crt -out alias.p12 -passout privada
```

Devuelve el error de que debe tener un valor válido,

> Invalid password argument "privada" Error getting passwords

Comment: Pues puedes ponerle `-passout lacontraseña` si es lo que quieres. Lo que no está claro es: qué quieres lograr con ese comando de openssl?

Comment: necesito encriptar un certificado, puedo hacer que -passout sea con valor nulo?

Comment: Cómo vas a encriptar un certificado sin un passphrase para el keystore?

Comment: He logrado ingresar una contraseña sin caracteres, al ingresarlo manualmente, ell procedimiento es meramente por pedido del sistema de certificados de mi pais, pero no es necesario!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que borrarle las claves privadas al certificado, prueba lo siguiente:

```
openssl rsa -in clave.pem -out certificado_original.pem
openssl dsa -in clave.pem -out certificado_original.pem
```

Pero como has indicado que tienes que hacerlo con pkcs12, prueba con esto otro:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -nodes -inkey clave.key -in certificado_original.crt -certfile certificado_destino.crt -passout pass:
```

Comment: Necesito que valla con pkcs12, para cifrar un certificado, y este cifrado es requerido por el sistema que se maneja en mi pais, no puedo quitarle el comando "pkcs12"

Comment: @Bernardo Harreguy echale un ojo, he modificado la respuesta

Comment: Gracias por todo